# MySQL: выбор клиента для Ubuntu

Tags: клиент, mysql

Какие есть удобные и понятные клиенты для работы с MySQL?

- phpmyadmin - как-то не серьёзно, да и надоел уже.
- heidisql - вещь довольно удобная, но на винде.
- razorsql - тоже не плохо, но требует лицензию.

Comment: HeidiSQL под Wine нормально ставится.

Comment: @Deonis wine это компромисс, а не решение

Comment: А мне так кажется, консоль лучше всего.

Comment: @Garfild на вкус и цвет все фломастеры разные

Comment: mysql (коммандлайновый клиент)

Answer (score 0):

Я пользуюсь хорошим и бесплатным инструментом Valentina Studio 5.x
http://www.valentina-db.com/valentina-studio-overview